# Synchronization of users between Google GSuite and Custom Application

Tags: single-sign-on, provisioning-profile, provisioning, google-workspace

I'm building a Google GSuite SSO (Single Sign-On) application, which will work with a custom software solution. There are 2 things I want to accomplish here:

1. Create SSO (using SAML) which will be Google Gsuite Directory application which can be installed.
2. Automatically create/update/delete new users inside my custom app when they are created in Google GSuite

Now, I'm not sure how to approach the 2nd problem. Basically, is there a way to make Google GSuite application which will send information about User Account changes to my custom application (something like a trigger, hook or provisioning for my custom application)?

Note: I can program a mechanism which will parse this data and synchronize users within my custom application, **I'm just not sure how to make Google GSuite to 'notify my application about any changes to the user accounts there'.**

I hope that this question makes sense, any kind of help, ideas and experiences are more than welcome.

p.s. I'm trying to do this for Microsoft Azure AD as well, so I posted the same type of question but for a different platform here [Synchronization of users between Microsoft Azure AD and Custom Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905025/synchronization-of-users-between-microsoft-azure-ad-and-custom-application)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Google Push Notification for Directory API. It provides notification for all user related event. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push